# Added Nest Hello to existing account - does not show in the devices GET

Tags: nest-device-access

I have a long-standing account with 2 nest thermostats in it, that I use to test my Nest device access integration.   I recently added a Nest Hello to the same account, which works and displays fine in the Nest app.

I used my Nest device access integration to query the devices, and the nest hello is not reported.

I re-oauth authorized, and the nest hello doesn't show in the choices of devices to enable access to (see attached screen shot).

Is there some setting in my device access project to enable doorbell access that I've missed?  Any other ideas what could be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with a nest camera. The image was showing in the nest app but the device was not listed. I added the nest device as a new product and it started to be listed properly.